# SQL SELECT between two non-joinable tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a two tables

```
Users
- ID

Preferences
- ID
- Name
- Value
```

There are no values between the two tables that can be joined on.

If I have two users and two preferences is there a way to get the following in a single SQL SELECT statement to get the following result:

```
User1.ID, Preference1.Name, Preference1.Value
User1.ID, Preference2.Name, Preference2.Value
User2.ID, Preference1.Name, Preference1.Value
User2.ID, Preference2.Name, Preference2.Value
```

Basically I would like to make a UserPreferences SQL View where every user is assigned every preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to create a `cartesian product`:

```
select u.id, p.name, p.value
from users u cross join preferences p
```

Comment: This could aslo be expressed as Select ... from users u, preferences p